# Proving $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + x + y + z \geq 2(xy+yz+zx)$ for positive values with $xyz=1$

Tags: inequality

> How can you prove that
> $$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + x + y + z \geq 2(xy+yz+zx)$$
> given that $x,y,z > 0$ and $xyz = 1$.

We can easily prove that the equality holds when $x = y = z = 1$

I could able to prove the result when one of $x,y,z$ is $1$ considering $x,y,z$ as $x,1/x, 1$ using the inequality $x + 1/x \geq 2$ for any positive number of $x$.

But couldn't able to find a full proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$f(x,y,z):=x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + x + y + z - 2(xy+yz+zx) \,.$$
Suppose WLOG that $x \ge y \ge z$, and write $g=\sqrt{xy}\,. \;$
Then
\begin{eqnarray} f(x,y,z)-f(g,g,z)&=& x^2+y^2-2g^2+(x+y-2g)(1-2z) \\ &=&
(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2 \cdot \Bigl( (\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})^2+1-2z\Bigr) \ge 0 \,,
\end{eqnarray}
since $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y} \ge 2\sqrt{z}. \;$ Moreover,
$$f(g,g,z)=z^2+2g+z-4gz \,,$$
so, recalling that $zg^2=zxy=1$, we get
$$g^4 f(g,g,z)=1+2g^5+g^2-4g^3=(g-1)^2(2g^3+4g^2+2g+1) \ge 0 \,.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=a^3, y=b^3, z=c^3$ then we have that $abc=1$ and we want to prove that $a^6+b^6+c^6+(a^3+b^3+c^3)=a^6+b^6+c^6+abc(a^3+b^3+c^3)\ge 2(a^3b^3+b^3c^3+c^3a^3)$. Now by [Schur's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_inequality) for $t=4$, $a^6+b^6+c^6+abc(a^3+b^3+c^3)\ge \sum_{sym} a^5b$ and by [Muirhead's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead%27s_inequality) $\sum_{sym} a^5b \ge \sum_{sym} a^3b^3=2(a^3b^3+b^3c^3+c^3a^3)$ and thus we are done.

Comment: @ Wizardooo1 - could explain little bit more about second stage of the proof?

Comment: @JanakaRodrigo this follows from the fact that $(5,1,0)$ majorizes $(3,3,0)$ because $5\ge 3, 5+1 \ge 3+3, 5+1+0=3+3+0$.

Answer (score 1):

*pqr method*:

Let $p = x + y + z, \, q = xy + yz + zx, \, r = xyz = 1$.

It suffices to prove that $p^2 - 2q + p \ge 2q$ or
$$p^2 + p - 4q \ge 0.$$

Using $p^3 - 4pq + 9r \ge 0$ (three degree Schur), we have
$$q \le \frac{p^3 + 9}{4p}.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$p^2 + p - 4\cdot \frac{p^3 + 9}{4p} \ge 0$$
or
$$(p - 3)(p + 3)/p \ge 0$$
which is true since $p\ge 3\sqrt[3]{r} = 3$ (AM-GM).

We are done.

*Remark*: Three degree Schur inequality is
$$x(x - y)(x - z) + y(y - z)(y - x) + z(z - x)(z - y) \ge 0.$$
In pqr language (or substitution), it is $p^3 - 4pq + 9r \ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Using $a = \ln(x)$, $b = \ln(y)$, $c = \ln(z)$, the problems's restriction can be reformulated as $a+b+c = 0$.
Note further that:

$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + x + y + z \geq 2(xy+yz+zx) \iff x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + x + y + z \geq 2(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z})$$

Consider now the function $f(t) = e^{2t}+e^{t}-2e^{-t}$ to rewrite our inequality as $f(a)+f(b)+f(c) = 0$ given $a+b+c = 0$.

Differentiating twice, we establish easily that $f(x)$ has only one inflection point. Thus, using the $n-1$-EV principle, we can deduce that for the minimum of this function to occur, two of the $a,b,c$, thus two of the $x,y,z$ need to have the same value.

Thus assume $x = y$, $z = \frac{1}{x^2}$.
Our inequality turns into:

$$2x^2+2x+{1\over x^4} + {1\over x^2} \geq 2\left(x^2+{2\over x}\right)$$
After manipulations, we obtain:
$$2x^5+ x^2  -4x^3+1 \geq 0 \iff \left(x-1\right)^2\left(2x^3+4x^2+2x+1\right)\geq 0$$

Which holds true for all positive $x$.

Comment: Sorry for the late post, I just saw this problem being approached by several different methods and wanted to add a new one of my own.